# Netbeans test in Java not printing

Tags: java, testing, netbeans, println

In a test class, I'm testing a implementation of a collection. All the assertions work just fine (therefore I know the methods on the class are working as I expect them to work). But everytime I use a System.out.println(String/Object) call the String won't show up in the test results... Does anybody know why this happens or how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String won't show up in the test results, but it will in the output console. It is designed to work like that.

Comment: Well I meant it didn't show up there either. But after changing the code of some methods it's working now.